# How to update an existing file based on column in tabulated pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following file `sample.txt` with the following data.

```
|    | Name              | Price       | 1h     | 24h     | MarketCap   | Volume     |
|---:|:------------------|:------------|:-------|:--------|:------------|:-----------|
| 21 | CRAZY PEPE        | 0.0...01394 | 20.70% | 278.85% | 139,419     | 470,435    |
| 12 | IL CAPO OF CRYPTO | 0.005524    | 20.11% | 191.03% | 5,524,020   | 10,996,033 |
| 14 | SPOODY            | 0.0...05661 | 4.26%  | 102.13% | 237,778     | 577,283    |
| 28 | Mad Bears Club    | 0.0238      | 0.60%  | 100.00% | 24          | --         |
| 29 | Solcasino Token   | 0.002232    | 0.69%  | 89.51%  | 22,320,931  | 2,530,342  |
```

How to update the sample.txt everytime the code is executed by appending some updated data ?

Currently, it updates the file by appending everything at the end.

```
Sample = "sample.txt"
open(Sample, 'a').close() #-- for append

import requests 
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/new/"
page = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=1)
pagedata = page.text
usecols = ["Name", "Price", "1h", "24h", "MarketCap", "Volume"]

df = pd.read_html(page.text)[0]
df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)
df = (df.rename(columns={"Fully Diluted Market Cap": "MarketCap"})[usecols]
          .sort_values("24h", ascending=False, key=lambda ser: ser.str.replace("%", "").astype(float))
          .replace(r"^\$", "", regex=True)
     )

numcols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['Name'])]
df = df.head(5).to_markdown(index=True)
print (df)

with open(Sample, 'a') as f:
    f.write("{}\n".format(df))
```

Possible Output: Additional 2 columns `(1h | 24H)` are added to the old file.

```
|    | Name              | Price       | 1h     | 24h     | MarketCap   | Volume     | Blockchain   | 1h     | 24h     |
|---:|:------------------|:------------|:-------|:--------|:------------|:-----------|:-------------|:-------|:--------|
| 21 | CRAZY PEPE        | 0.0...01397 | 20.31% | 279.52% | 139,665     | 470,454    | BNB          | 21.45% | 265.10% |
| 12 | IL CAPO OF CRYPTO | 0.005693    | 12.26% | 199.93% | 5,692,970   | 11,009,159 | BNB          | 150.00%| 500.00% |
| 14 | SPOODY            | 0.0...05658 | 5.21%  | 102.00% | 237,618     | 577,283    | Ethereum     | 15.95% | 98.00%  |
| 28 | Mad Bears Club    | 0.0238      | 0.31%  | 100.00% | 24          | --         | Solana       | 4.76%  | 175.87% |
| 29 | Solcasino Token   | 0.002252    | 1.69%  | 91.19%  | 22,519,338  | 2,530,229  | Solana       | 15.97% | 101.45% |



#--> 21 and 28 are not on the sample.txt but updated after the script is run.

|    | Name              | Price       | 1h     | 24h     | MarketCap   | Volume     | Blockchain   | 1h     | 24h     |
|---:|:------------------|:------------|:-------|:--------|:------------|:-----------|:-------------|:-------|:--------|
| 21 | BUTTER            | 0.0...01397 | 10.87% | 165.00% | 5,010       | 100,000    | Ethereum     | 81.00% | 765.10% |
| 12 | IL CAPO OF CRYPTO | 0.005693    | 12.26% | 199.93% | 5,692,970   | 11,009,159 | BNB          | 150.00%| 500.00% |
| 14 | SPOODY            | 0.0...05658 | 5.21%  | 102.00% | 237,618     | 577,283    | Ethereum     | 15.95% | 98.00%  |
| 28 | GUCCI           | 0.0238      | 0.31%  | 100.00% | 24          | --         | Solana       | 4.76%  | 175.87% |
| 29 | Solcasino Token   | 0.002252    | 1.69%  | 91.19%  | 22,519,338  | 2,530,229  | Solana       | 15.97% | 101.45% |
```

Comment: What if in the next actualisation, for example CRAZY PEPE is not in the top 5 or may have changed of rank ? In other terms, what should be the new 1h and 24 in the text file (*in those cases*) for the first row ?

Comment: I updated the post, thank you for the idea. I have not thought of that.

Comment: Would you mind looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76226066/columns-must-be-same-length-as-key-error-when-trying-split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
     # ...  # rest of code
    .sort_values("24h", ascending=False,
                 key=lambda ser: ser.str.replace("%", "").astype(float))
    .replace(r"^\$", "", regex=True)
)
    
df = df.head(5)
```

---

```
old = (
    pd.read_csv("sample.txt", sep=r"|", index_col=[1])
        .dropna(axis=1).iloc[1:].rename(str.strip, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(index="idx").replace(r"^\s*|\s*$", "", regex=True)
)

out = (old.reset_index().merge(df[["Name", "1h", "24h"]], on="Name", how="left")
           .rename(lambda x: x.split("_")[0], axis=1)
           .set_index("idx").rename_axis(index=None))

with open("sample.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(f"{out.to_markdown()}")
```

Output (*sample.txt*) :

```
|      | Name              | Price       | 1h     | 24h     | MarketCap   | Volume     | 1h     | 24h     |
|-----:|:------------------|:------------|:-------|:--------|:------------|:-----------|:-------|:--------|
|  21  | CRAZY PEPE        | 0.0...01394 | 20.70% | 278.85% | 139,419     | 470,435    | 21.34% | 221.08% |
|  12  | IL CAPO OF CRYPTO | 0.005524    | 20.11% | 191.03% | 5,524,020   | 10,996,033 | 12.18% | 135.17% |
|  14  | SPOODY            | 0.0...05661 | 4.26%  | 102.13% | 237,778     | 577,283    | 8.60%  | 81.97%  |
|  28  | Mad Bears Club    | 0.0238      | 0.60%  | 100.00% | 24          | --         | 0.01%  | 100.00% |
|  29  | Solcasino Token   | 0.002232    | 0.69%  | 89.51%  | 22,320,931  | 2,530,342  | 3.71%  | 92.67%
```