# 'Columns must be same length as key' error when trying .Split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below just runs fine with Python 3.8.10 but does not run in Python 3.10. Any idea what could be the problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/new/"
page = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=1)
pagedata = page.text
usecols = ["Name", "Symbol", "1h", "24h", "MarketCap"]


df = pd.read_html(page.text)[0]
df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)

df = (df.rename(columns={"Fully Diluted Market Cap": "MarketCap"})[usecols]
          .sort_values("24h", ascending=False, key=lambda ser: ser.str.replace("%", "").astype(float))
          .replace(r"^\$", "", regex=True)
     )

numcols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['Name'])]
df = df.head(5).to_markdown(index=True)
print (df)
```

Current Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)
  ....
  ....
  ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Correct Output: (Output in Python 3.8)

```
|    | Name        | Symbol    | 1h     | 24h      | MarketCap   |
|---:|:------------|:----------|:-------|:---------|:------------|
|  3 | Shrekt      |4HREK      | 23.82% | 2536.51% | 342,357     |
|  8 | BLAZE       |TOKEN9BLZE | 1.07%  | 106.71%  | 3,828,088   |
| 26 | Goner27     |GONER      | 6.32%  | 88.09%   | 1,094,010   |
| 14 | Party Hat15 |PHAT       | 13.34% | 81.64%   | 60,136      |
| 29 | PepeChat    |30PPC      | 48.01% | 78.25%   | 431,159     |
```

Comment: Note that "Name" in some cases have values with no "SPACE" or with a few "SPACE"s. What do you want to do in this case?

Comment: What could be the best option just to get the Correct Output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with one of the values (`NOOT (BRC-20)4NOOT`) found in the column `Name`.

To handle this, we can try to split on the last number found in each row of this column.

Replace this :

```
df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)
```

By this :

```
df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+(?!.*\d)", expand=True)
```

> Regex [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/QNoYpo/1)]

Output :

```
print(df)

|    | Name        | Symbol   | 1h     | 24h      | MarketCap   |
|---:|:------------|:---------|:-------|:---------|:------------|
|  5 | Shrekt      | HREK     | 54.61% | 1124.57% | 159,013     |
| 10 | BLAZE TOKEN | BLZE     | 2.40%  | 109.53%  | 3,880,242   |
|  8 | CMC DOGE    | CMCDOGE  | 12.93% | 102.76%  | 169,492     |
| 28 | Goner       | GONER    | 1.37%  | 88.66%   | 1,050,089   |
|  4 | nomeme      | NOMEME   | 53.86% | 86.14%   | 4,603,393   |
```

Comment: I thought it gas something to do with updating to 3.10 version of python. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use keep using df as dataframe. I think you can create a new one and use that one after the function. Try just doing this

```
newDF = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)
print(newDF)
```

Edit Fixed Code:

```
df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.replace("\(BRC-20\)","")
```

add this line to your code which will replace anything that has (BRC-20) in it.
So the problem wasn't being about the version of your python.

Comment: I'm gonna use the comments to answer your question after splitting second row breaks your code

Comment: With errors like these you should always check what your output of your function is

Comment: `df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.replace("(BRC-20)","")` gives me the column result `Shrekt5HREK, CMC DOGE8CMCDOGE`

Comment: What do you need to get ?

Comment: The Correct Output above, I wanted to get the same result as it was in 3.8

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to split the name by the value of columns '#'.
You can do it like this:

Create a function for splitting:

```
def splitting(num, strng):
    splitted = strng.split(str(num))
    print (num)
    return [splitted[0], splitted[1]]
```

Then apply the function and explode the new column into new columns:

```
df["split"] = df.apply(lambda x: splitting(x['#'], x['Name']), axis=1)
df[['OnlyName','Symbol']] = pd.DataFrame(df.split.tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Using this code, some are being split and some are not.

Comment: The one that are not splitted are ones with no SPACE

Comment: Is there a way to properly do it? I wanted to have the same output as it was in 3.8

Comment: See updated answer above